# VBA Time Conversion

Tags: excel, vba

I've autogenerated time from an API in the format "15-03-2022 01:10", here I would like to take the timepart and convert it to 13:10 and so on. As there is no AM/PM at the end of time, it is getting difficult to apply the Excel time format, is there any way I can achieve this using excel VBA.

I Searched everywhere, but couldn't find the correct solution for the above issue. Some example like
11:30  --> 11:30 Morning
11:30  --> 23:30 Night
just trying to figure out how to distinguish between the above 2 formats in a single day. But the end output needs to be in 24hr format.

Comment: How do you know that "01:10" in "15-03-2022 01:10" actually corresponds to 13:10, and not 01:10? Given the data you shared, this seems ... impossible. Do you actually have a series of timestamps in sequential order?

Comment: I do recollect that I Saw one post asking same question in another forum, but unable to get that site link, in that he modified using excel formula just the hr part to be displayed as 24hr format. I think he compared to something. so that 12:00AM is getting displayed  as 00:00. I tried to search that link like a day.. but no luck.. yes, the values will get generated between 9:00AM in morning to 5:00PM till evening, is there anyway we can modify.

Comment: Given that the data is between 9AM-5PM, you can convert the timestamp to a date using `CDate`, and then use `Hour` to determine whether the timestamp corresponds to AM or PM.

Answer (score 0):

Every day in Excel is 1, so half a day is 0.5.

`CDate("15-03-2022 01:10") + 0.5` to add half a day.

Also you can concatenate PM to the end of the string

`CDate("15-03-2022 01:10 PM")`

Then you can output any display text you want with the [Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications) function.

`Format(MyTime, "MMM dd, hh:mm:ss am/pm")` would display "Mar 15, 01:10:00 PM"

For 24 Hour time formatting, remove the am/pm:

`Format(MyTime, "MMM dd, hh:mm:ss")` would display "Mar 15, 13:10:00"

Comment: Doesn't this assume that 01:10 is always 01:10 PM? What if it's 01:10 AM?

Comment: @BigBen The post is asking a few questions, I am choosing to focus on the first question I saw, which is "it is getting difficult to apply the Excel time format, is there any way I can achieve this using excel VBA". I would need more details from Kiran if I were to attempt to advise about how to determine AM vs PM without just assuming PM.

Answer (score 0):

Always handle date and time as *Date*, not text, no exceptions. So:

```
NewTime = DateAdd("h", 12, CDate("15-03-2022 01:10"))
```

Then apply the format you wish for display, here:

```
dd-mm-yyyy hh:nn
```